# How to compile and run C/C++ in Debian-based linux?

Tags: atom-editor

I recently installed Atom Editor in my Kali Vm but I am unable to compile and run c/c++ programs.What can I do in order to implement this?

Comment: Do you have a compiler in your path? `gcc/g++` or `clang/clang++` You installing an editor should have nothing to do with you being unable to compile.

Comment: @HSchmale of course, I have gcc/g++ compiler preinstalled since I am using kali linux

Comment: Install https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler

Comment: @Piers C how to install it? I mean from terminal or package generator of atom-editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install [gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp) from [Atom Settings/Install](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/)

Comment: @Pierc C thanks. It worked .Can you please suggest the package to run python also?

Comment: You may want to look at [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui) and [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python) but that is really another question.